# is there any code which identifies a particular cell ( b2) true and then subsitute the formula in another cell (i2)?

Tags: excel, vba, excel-formula

[the yellow highighted is where the data is entered](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TWwUw.png) lets say cell b2 is data entry.. and i2 to AD2 are the cells in which formulas are suppose to be set.

i need a vba code which identifies b2 = any amount/symbol if its true, I2 to ad2 should insert this if formula [[IF($I$1=D2,G2,"")]

This should be applied in all the rows

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please place this in your **worksheet's module**.

It checks, whether cell B2 is changed and contains something, and then places the formula in whole range, starting at I2:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim RelevantArea As Range
    Dim lastRow As Long

    Set RelevantArea = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B2"))
    If Not RelevantArea Is Nothing Then
        If Len(Target.Value2) > 0 Then
            ' find the last used row, e. g. in column 9:
            lastRow = Me.Cells(Me.Rows.Count, 9).End(xlUp).Row
            Application.EnableEvents = False
            Me.Range("I2:AD" & lastRow).Formula = "=IF(I$1=$D2,$G2,"""")"
            Application.EnableEvents = True
        End If
    End If
End Sub
```

The formula is inserted into the range like you would get it, if you copy the formula of the first cell (here: I2) to the rest of the range. I changed the formula a little, assuming you wanted it like that.

By following you get it for the changed row only, i. e. if you paste into e. g. B5:B9, it works for rows 5 to 9.
You can use the A1- or R1C1-notation to adapt the formula to your needs.

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
    Dim MonitoredArea As Range
    Dim CurrentRow As Long
    Dim CurrentCell As Range

    Set MonitoredArea = Intersect(Target, Me.Range("B:B"))
    If Not MonitoredArea Is Nothing Then
        For Each CurrentCell In MonitoredArea.Cells
            If Len(CurrentCell.Value2) > 0 Then
                CurrentRow = CurrentCell.Row
                Application.EnableEvents = False
                With Me.Range(Me.Cells(CurrentRow, "I"), Me.Cells(CurrentRow, "AD"))
                    .Formula = "=IF(I$1=$D" & CurrentRow & ",$G" & CurrentRow & ","""")"
                    '.FormulaR1C1 = "=IF(R1C=RC4,RC7,"""")"

                    Dim i As Integer
                    For i = xlEdgeLeft To xlInsideHorizontal  ' all borders
                        With .Borders(i)
                            .LineStyle = xlContinuous
                            .Weight = xlThin
                            .Color = RGB(0, 0, 0)
                            .TintAndShade = 0
                        End With
                    Next i

                End With
                Application.EnableEvents = True
            End If
        Next CurrentCell
    End If
End Sub
```

Comment: If you copied it in your worksheet‘s module (not ThisWorkbook) and write something into cell B2, some new formula should be seen, starting in cells I2:AD2 and below.

Comment: it worked but i want this code to work on each row seperately 
for e.g if b2 contains a number/symbol then i2 to ad2 should insert the formula
 same as when b3 contains a number/symbol then i3 to ad3 should insert the number and goes on 
unless column b rows doesnt contain any thing the rest of the sheet should remain empty

thanks

Comment: can u add a code of "all borders" in this same code. like as the formula is inserted in the same range of cell that is i2:ad2 cell should aplly all borders too

Comment: @Malcolm I wrote the code for you, I corrected your formula, I added code for the borders and you already said "it worked thanks alot". Now I kindly ask you again to mark my answer as answer. If you don't know how, please refer to https://stackoverflow.com/help/someone-answers.